# gdb print inconsistency

Tags: debugging, gdb, gnu

I have some code

```
 int main(int argc, char* key[] ) {
 cout << strlen(key[1]) << endl;
```

cout show 4. 
now using gdb

```
(gdb)print strlen(key[1])
```

shows -147660784 
What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27019/strlen-returns-incorrect-value-when-called-in-gdb

Comment: This question relates to tools that programmers use, it is perfectly on topic for SO (even though it has been asked on another site).

Answer (score 3):

Could it be related to this bug? http://osdir.com/ml/debian-bugs-dist/2010-09/msg00019.html

Comment: It most likely is the same bug.